# Is it possible to use an Initialiser with the Doctrine Entity Manager to set up entities?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, entities

I would like to pass some path variables into a doctrine entity (using Zend2) which deals with uploaded files (using http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html as a basis).

I'm able to do so via the constructor (and was intending to create a factory to do this for me)

$medium = new \Application\Entity\Medium('/path/to/filestore')

but this isn't an option when I use $medium = $entityManager->find('Application\Entity\Medium', $id);

Does anyone have any ideas how best to proceed? Is it possible to tell the entityManager which factory to use to grab entities?

Thanks!

Comment: The entity should never handle anything. It is just a persistent data container. If you need something done in the context of an entity, create a service for that.

Comment: https://juriansluiman.nl/article/142/dependency-injection-in-a-doctrine-repository suggests adding a custom repository class

Comment: @lxg - Thanks for the suggestion. I agree with you in principle - do you suggest passing the entity to a service which extracts the relevant data and creates the file? The only caveat I have is that without the final filename (and the movement of the file from temp to a permanent store), the data store is incomplete so you could argue that it does fall under the purview of the entity...